# Can't Get Multiple Different Queries To Run

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code running on my website

```
if($_GET['approve']) {
            $tmppass = randomPassword();
            $dbpass = md5('nosaltforyou'.md5($tmppass).'nosaltforyou');
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "php", "password", "icegc");
            $row = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `applications` WHERE `id` = ".$_GET['approve']);
            mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (null, '".$row['nickname']."','$dbpass','".$row['steamlink']."','".$row['tmplink']."','".$row['icevtc']."','".$row['csgo']."','member'");
            mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM `applications` WHERE `id` = ".$_GET['approve']);
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong>Warning!</strong> Send This Password: '.$tmppass.' To <a href="'.$row['steamlink'].'" class="alert-link">This Steam Profile</a>
                  </div>';
            mysqli_close($conn);
        }
```

and what is supposed to do is approve an application to join the site by adding it to my users table and deleting it from my applications table. I am not getting anything changed in the database and there is not output to the webpage. Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$row` where is that populated from? that requires a pre-fetch

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for me to test it, but try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['approve'])){
    try {
        $tmppass = randomPassword();
        $dbpass = md5('nosaltforyou'.md5($tmppass).'nosaltforyou');
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "php", "password", "icegc");
        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `applications` WHERE `id`=?")){
            $stmt->bind_param('i', intval($_GET['approve']));
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
        }
        if($mysqli->errno){
            throw new Exception('MySQL error: '.$mysqli->error);
        }
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
            $steamlink = $row['steamlink'];
            if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")){
                $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $row['nickname'], $dbpass, $steamlink, $row['tmplink'], $row['icevtc'], $row['csgo'], 'member');
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            if($mysqli->errno){
                throw new Exception('MySQL error: '.$mysqli->error);
            }
            if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM `applications` WHERE `id`=?")){
                $stmt->bind_param('i', intval($_GET['approve']));
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            if($mysqli->errno){
                throw new Exception('MySQL error: '.$mysqli->error);
            }
        }
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <strong>Warning!</strong> Send This Password: '.$tmppass.' To <a href="'.$steamlink.'" class="alert-link">This Steam Profile</a>
        </div>';
        $mysqli->close();
    } catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```